# Is spawning threads inside of threads standard or bad practice?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

In short: Is spawning threads inside of threads a standard procedure or should this be avoided if possible?

An example: Think of a parallel spider retrieving and parsing multiple documents at once.
In my reasoning the spider in question would need two threads(FetcherPool, ParserPool) spawning Fetcher- and Parser worker threads in order to make everything work concurrently(see below).

Example:

```
Main Thread  
|------FetcherPool  
|      |------Fetcher  
|      |------Fetcher  
|  
|------ParserPool 
       |------Parser  
       |------Parser
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - because you can't spawn a thread from anything else. The very first thread that you spawn in your script is spawned from the "main" thread. If you execute "Thread.current" in a non-multithreaded app, you'll get this main thread. "Thread.main" also returns it.

But if your question is about spawning from threads other than "main", I don't think there's anything inherently bad about that either. For your own (or your team's) sanity, you should design the thread management so workers don't get out of control (e.g. spawning more than you intended). Code readability and controlling access to shared resources should also be considered.

Here's an interesting article about the issues with multithreading: http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-1.pdf

In general, it's a good idea to encapsulate your threads into objects and just call methods on those. It makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: I realize this is a bit late. I still want to thank you for your  great answer. You're making a good point there about keeping the code simple.

Comment: @deRailed You're welcome. One other thing I forgot to mention - the built-in `Queue` (and its subclass `SizedQueue`) is very helpful for safe inter-thread communication. I also recommend reading up on `Monitor` and `MonitorMixin`.